# How to set up vhosts on Mac OS for zend framework?

Tags: php, mac-osx, zend-framework, virtualhost

I've added a virtual host in my vhosts file like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com

DocumentRoot "/Users/myname/Sites/test/public"

ServerName test

<Directory "/Users/myname/Sites/test/public">

    AllowOverride All

</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

My zend project is in the path "/Users/myname/Sites/test", called it test

Also, in the hosts file, I've this

127.0.0.1 test

These are the exact same steps I did on Windows, where it works correctly.  But on Mac, it doesn't.  I get

"Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /test/public/ on this server" error.

What else am I missing?

My rewrite module is on

Answer (score 1):

Finally, after wasting a couple of hours, found the solution
I had to add
Options +FollowSymLinks
within the Directory :(

Thanks everyone, who answered

Comment: Good to know. :-) Interestingly, I had this commented out in my file, hence why it did not appear in my answer. Apparently I had to comment it out to make it work for me. Glad you made it work.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have mod_access enabled? You may need to add this inside your Directory stanza:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

Comment: How do I enable mod_access? There is no loadmodule mod_access in httpd.conf :(

Comment: Hmm, if it's not even loaded then I think it defaults to allow all, so I guess that makes my answer irrelevant. How about permissions? Make sure that the directory your project is in can be read by the user running Apache.

Comment: I even tried 777, it still doesn't work

Comment: What does your Apache error_log show for the hit?

Comment: Options FollowSymLinks or SymLinksIfOwnerMatch is off which implies that RewriteRule directive is forbidden: /Users/myname/Sites/test/public/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that you have restarted your web server. I got that error too a few days ago after having changed the paths without restarting.

Below is part of my `httpd-vhosts.conf` on OS X Lion 10.7 and AMPSS.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName zend.local
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
DocumentRoot "/Users/Andy/dev/quickstart/public"
<Directory "/Users/Andy/dev/quickstart/public">
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    allow from All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, still not working.  And yes, I did restart Apache, using "sudo apachectl restart"